# How do I force Outlook VBA to use a specific address book?

Tags: vba, outlook

I've written a script that forwards incoming emails to the right people based on the contents of an excel spreadsheet.

The problem is it that does this by putting the name of the addressee into the `.To` field of the message (ie John Smith - not john.smith@example.com), and then looking up the actual address when I invoke the `.Send` method, Outlook seems to decide to sometimes look up the contacts email address via the *"LinkedIn Social Connector"*.

How do I force it to look up the person's email address in the *"Global Address List"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the address from the GAL rather letting Outlook determine it.

From the example here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869721(v=office.15).aspx

Untested code

```
Option Explicit

Sub DemoAE_ToName

    Dim colAL As Outlook.AddressLists 
    Dim oAL As Outlook.AddressList 
    Dim colAE As Outlook.AddressEntries 
    Dim oAE As Outlook.AddressEntry 
    Dim oExUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser 

    Set colAL = Application.Session.AddressLists 

    For Each oAL In colAL 

        'Address list is an Exchange Global Address List 
         If oAL.AddressListType = olExchangeGlobalAddressList Then

            Set colAE = oAL.AddressEntries 

            For Each oAE In colAE 

                ' no distribution lists
                If oAE.AddressEntryUserType = _
                    olExchangeUserAddressEntry _ 
                  Or oAE.AddressEntryUserType = _
                    olExchangeRemoteUserAddressEntry Then 

                    If oAE.Name = "John Smith" then
                        Set oExUser = oAE.GetExchangeUser 
                        Debug.Print (oExUser.PrimarySmtpAddress)
                    end if

                End If 

             Next 

         End If 

     Next 

End Sub
```

You can set up a function to pass ToName and return oExUser.PrimarySmtpAddress

Rather than

```
For Each oAL In colAL
    If oAL.AddressListType = olExchangeGlobalAddressList Then
```

You should be able to drop some code with

```
Set oAL = Application.Session.AddressLists("Global Address List")
```

---

Edit: Re: Comments - Tough crowd.

Edit 2: Appears Restrict is not available

Tested Code where the address is retrieved when the name is known.

```
Sub AddressEntry_DirectAccess()

    Dim oNS As Namespace
    Dim oExUser As exchangeUser

    Set oNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oExUser = oNS.AddressLists("Global Address List").AddressEntries("Last, First").GetExchangeUser()

    If Not oExUser Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print oExUser.name & ": " & oExUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: That looks like it would do the trick, but I'd be looping over all employees, is there a search function that might be faster?

Comment: Looping through all entries in GAL is a horrible idea.

Comment: Edit 2 - Replaced speculative code with working code.

Comment: To be clear, the "Tested Code" with `.AddressEntries("Last, First").GetExchangeUser()` works perfectly, the remainder isn't best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can specify the right name resolution order in Outlook if you hit Ctrl+Shift+B, Tools | Options.

If you were using C++ or Delphi, you could use Extended MAPI: retrieve the GAL's `IABContainer` interface and apply `PR_ANR` restriction.

If you using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, you can use [RDOSession.AddressBook.GAL](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdoaddressbook.htm) to retrieve the GAL container, then use [RDOAddressList.ResolveName](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAddressList.htm) to resolve against that particular container only.